# Load NeTEx file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, xml

I have this XML file that is in NeTEx format
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fKHW81oGTiRxmuINLKie6yariLUA9LCP/view?usp=sharing

I downloaded it from this website
https://www.trafiklab.se/api/trafiklab-apis/stops-data/

How do I load it in Qgis?

Comment: can you use the GTFS format instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML comes in various formats depending on the purpose set by the developers behind it. You can view it using software such as Notepad ++ . You will not be able to open it in QGIS for GIS work though as I know. The _stops.xml data file you provided has more than 900,000 records in it. Below are some options I would use to get the data converted:

1. You can use FME Form (previously known as FME Desktop) to convert your data from XML to CSV. You can download and request for a trial license and test it out ([www.safe.com](http://www.safe.com))

[image]

2. You can open the data in MS Excel, it take a long time to load it though and you need to be patient, see picture below:

[image]

You could then export the file in a CSV format.

3. If you can download the GTFS format, you could load it in QGIS using the GTFS Loader or GTFS-GO plugins.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!